# Partial sum of Combination Induction Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

How do I prove the following?

$\binom{n}{1} + 2\binom{n}{2}+ 3\binom{n}{3}+...+n\binom{n}{n}=n2^{n-1}$

$\forall n\epsilon \mathbb{N}$

Base Case:

$\binom{1}{1} = (1)2^{1-1}$

$1=1\;$, Which is True.

With $\;n=k$ let us assume that

$\binom{k}{1} + 2\binom{k}{2}+ 3\binom{k}{3}+...+k\binom{k}{k}=k2^{k-1}\;$
is true

then, for n=k+1 we have

$\binom{k+1}{1} + 2\binom{k+1}{2}+ 3\binom{k+1}{3}+...+k\binom{k+1}{k+!}=(k+1)2^{k}\;$

We know that

$_{}^{k}\textrm{C}_{r}=\frac{k!}{r!(k-r)!}$

then our inductive hypothesis can be seen as:

$\frac{k!}{k!(k-1)!} +2\frac{k!}{k!(k-2)!}+ 3\frac{k!}{k!(k-3)!} ...+k\frac{k!}{k!(k-k)!} = k2^{k-1}$

and what we need to prove should look like:

$\frac{(k+1)!}{(k+1)!(k)!} +2\frac{(k+1)!}{(k+1)!(k-1)!}+ 3\frac{(k+1)!}{(k+1)!(k-2)!} ...+(k+1)\frac{(k+1)!}{(k+1)!(k+1-k-1)!} = (k+1)2^{k}$

Is this the way to proceed? How would you proceed? Please show me the way, I am stuck.

Comment: Try differentiating $(1+x)^n$ in two different ways.

Comment: @Oussema's hint gets you a clean and simple solution, but if you want to do induction, just note that $(n+1)2^n-n2^{n-1}=2^n+n2^{n-1}$.

Comment: If you want a proof by induction, then consider Pascal's identity.

Comment: I will look into Pascals Identity thank you

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't actually go down the induction route. We know from the binomial theorem that $(1+x)^n=1+\binom n1 x+\binom n2 x^2+\cdots +\binom nn 1$. Notice that $(1+1)^n=2^n$, where we have set $x=1$. Now differentiate this - we get $x+2\binom n2 x+3\binom n3 x^2+\cdots$. Can you see how to finish this proof?